# Issue with query in DB2

Tags: sql-server, db2

I was using below query in sql server to update the table "TABLE" using the same table "TABLE". In sql server the below query is working fine.But in DB2 its getting failed.Not sure whether I need to make any change in this query to work in DB2.

The error I am getting in DB2 is

> ExampleExceptionFormatter: exception message was: DB2 SQL Error:
>   SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704

This is my input Data and there you can see ENO 679 is repeating in both round 3 and round 4.

[image]

My expected output is given below. Here I am taking the ID and round value from round 4 and updating rownumber 3 with the ID value from rownumber 4.

[image]

My requirement is to find the ENO which is exist in both round 3 and round 4 and update the values accordingly.

```
UPDATE  TGT 
SET TGT.ROUND = SRC.ROUND, 
TGT.ID = SRC.ID
FROM TABLE TGT INNER  JOIN TABLE SRC
ON TGT.ROUND='3' and SRC.ROUND='4' and TGT.ENO = SRC.ENO
```

Could someone help here please. I tried something like this.But its not working

```
UPDATE TABLE
    SET ID = (SELECT t.ID
                FROM TABLE t, TABLE t2
                WHERE t.ENO = t2.ENO AND t.ROUND= ='4' AND t2.ROUND='3'

               ) ,
ROUND= (SELECT t.ROUND
                FROM TABLE t, TABLE t2
                WHERE t.ENO = t2.ENO AND t.ROUND= ='4' AND t2.ROUND='3')
where ROUND='3'
```

Comment: Can you show us the error, input output, table structure ?

Comment: share your exact table structure and error message from above query

Comment: what is the issue in your first query....so you wrote this second query

Comment: My first query is working fine in sql server. But the same query is not working in DB2

Comment: If your Db2-server platform+version supports it, then I would use the MERGE statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL update from one Table to another based on a ID match IN db2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285136/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match-in-db2)

Comment: [SQL0204N](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic1.html#sql0204n) error code means, that you try to use an undefined object in your query. What’s the full Db2 message you get?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. I think the issue is you are not relating your inner subquery with outer main table

```
UPDATE TABLE TB
    SET TB.ID = (SELECT t.ID
                FROM TABLE t, TABLE t2
                WHERE TB.ENO=t.ENO     ----  added this
                 and t.ENO = t2.ENO AND t.ROUND= ='4' AND t2.ROUND='3'
               ) ,
TB.ROUND= (SELECT t.ROUND
                FROM TABLE t, TABLE t2
                WHERE TB.ENO=t.ENO    --- added this
                and t.ENO = t2.ENO AND t.ROUND= ='4' AND t2.ROUND='3')
where tb.ROUND='3'
```

Comment: Thanks. But still I am getting some error .ExampleExceptionFormatter: exception message was: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: see this link to get the details about your error and resolve it..https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21965866

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE MY_SAMPLE TGT
SET (ID, ROUND) = (SELECT ID, ROUND FROM MY_SAMPLE WHERE ENO = TGT.ENO AND ROUND = 4)
WHERE ROUND = 4 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MY_SAMPLE WHERE ENO = TGT.ENO AND ROUND = 4);
```

The difference with yours is that the correlated subquery has to be a row-subselect, it has to guarantee zero or one row (and will assign nulls in case of returning zero rows). The EXISTS subquery excludes rows for which the correlated subquery will not return rows.