# JOIN in UPDATE sql for DB2

Tags: join, db2, sql-update

Is there a way to use joins in update statements for DB2?

Google has really let me down.

This is roughly what I'm trying to achieve (... except obviously working ....)

```
Update gk.WR_VEHICLE_WARRANTY w
         join gk.VGARANT_FRIST_ZUWEIS z
              on z.PK_GARANT_FRIST_ZUWEIS = w.FK_GARANT_FRIST_ZUWEIS
set CURRENT = '1'

where z.GW = '1'
  and z.FK_GBE is null
  and z.INTERN = '0';
```

Comment: Use [MERGE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html) statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL update from one Table to another based on a ID match IN db2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285136/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match-in-db2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem , just took out the join and did a inner select

```
Update gk.WR_VEHICLE_WARRANTY 
set CURRENT = '1'
Where FK_GARANT_FRIST_ZUWEIS in 
(select PK_GARANT_FRIST_ZUWEIS from gk.VGARANT_FRIST_ZUWEIS z
where z.GW = '1'
  and z.FK_GBE is null
  and z.INTERN = '0' )
```