# SQL update on one table checking condition from another table

Tags: database, db2, sql-update, inner-join

I am querying a column using the below statement:

```
SELECT t1.col1 from table1 t1, table2 t2  
WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col2 and t2.col3 IN (data1, data2);
```

I am trying to update the t1.col1 satisfying the above where condition but I get errors.

here is the update statement I tried:

```
update t1 set t1.col1 = 1 from table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 where t2.col3 IN ( data1, data2 );
```

I want to update the value of t1.col1 if the listed data matches the data in t2.col3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL update from one Table to another based on a ID match IN db2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285136/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match-in-db2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use correlated subquery syntax here:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET col1 = 1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.col2 = t1.col1 AND t2.col3 IN (data1, data2));
```