# How to fix "SQL Error Keyword FROM not expected" in db2?

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update

I have this query that I need to update

```
UPDATE pomhst hst
   SET hst.ponot1 = hdr.poshp1 
  FROM pomhdr hdr
 WHERE LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(hst.poshp1))) > 0
   AND hdr.postat = 3;
```

and when I execute it, it shows this error

> SQL Error [42601]: [SQL0199] Keyword FROM not expected. Valid tokens: USE SKIP WAIT WITH FETCH LIMIT ORDER WHERE OFFSET.
> I do not know what is wrong with my query

I tried adding inner join but it didnt work as well.

Comment: What's you db2 platform and version?

Answer (score 1):

Some Database Management System such as `Oracle`, `DB2` doesn't support the syntax

`UPDATE a_table SET .. FROM another_table` unlike to some others such as `Postgres`.

You can alternatively use a `MERGE` statement as the below one :

```
MERGE INTO pomhst hst
     USING pomhdr AS hdr
        ON LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(hst.poshp1)))  > 0 
       AND postat = 3
       AND hdr.id = hst.id
      WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET hst.ponot1 = hdr.poshp1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/bCGWYZ4G)</kbd>

Comment: Also, it's a non-standard syntax.

Comment: Thanks @jarlh you were right, just edited.

Comment: FWIW, Db2 also supports: `MERGE INTO pomhst hst
     USING pomhdr AS hdr
        ON hdr.id = hst.id
      WHEN MATCHED 
       AND LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(hst.poshp1))) > 0 
       AND postat = 3 
          THEN UPDATE SET hst.ponot1 = hdr.poshp1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use exists:

```
UPDATE pomhst hst SET hst.ponot1 = hdr.poshp1 
WHERE exists (select *  from FROM pomhdr hdr where LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(hst.POSHP1)))  > 0 AND hdr.POSTAT = 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

DB2 still does not support joins in update statements, so you'll need to use [MERGE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=statements-merge);

OR, You can simply do it using a subquery as follows :

```
update pomhst hst 
set hst.ponot1 = (
    select hdr.poshp1 
    from pomhdr hdr 
    where hdr.ponum = hst.ponum and hdr.POSTAT = 3
) 
where LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(hst.POSHP1))) > 0;
```

Here is a [similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285136/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match-in-db2).